# Как использовать API yandex speller-а для проверки на орфографические ошибки в тексте на Ruby

Tags: api, ruby

Я только начинаю изучение Ruby и понимаю лишь идею реализации данного вопроса, надеюсь правильно. Мне необходимо создать метод или класс, который на вход будет принимать текст и обрабатывать его с помощью API yandex speller-а и возвращать проверенный текст. Я предполагаю, что это должно просто решаться, но то что я нахожу в просторах интернета, мне непонятно. Будет здорово если вы знаете где искать нужную информацию и подскажите.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант простого решения

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
s = "Мама мыла раммму"
# выполняем запрос
# сложная конструкция связанна с тем, что URL необходимо "подготовить"
response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(URI.encode("https://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice.json/checkText?text=#{s}")))
JSON.parse(response)
# [{"code"=>1, "pos"=>10, "row"=>0, "col"=>10, "len"=>6, "word"=>"раммму", "s"=>["раму", "рамму", "рому", "ранму"]}]
```

На счет поиска информации:

- документация на спеллер - https://yandex.ru/dev/speller/doc/dg/concepts/api-overview.html
- статьи по теме выполнения HTTP запросов, напр. https://www.twilio.com/blog/5-ways-make-http-requests-ruby
- документация на модуль `Net::HTTP` https://rubyapi.org/2.6/o/net/http